# Why isn't python seeing changes I make to the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm attempting to customize the parser/lexer for the httpdomain Sphinx doc extension. I installed in a given dir and added the dir to the sys.path as mentioned in the docs.

I then compile the Sphinx doc and http gets highlighted properly.

Now, I need to make a small change to the extension. I started by making a random change to the httpdomain.py file inside the extension's dir, which correctly yielded an error for invalid syntax.

Next, I changed the lexer by replacing the HTTP token with HTTTP (one extra T). My idea is to see if now entries in the doc containing HTTTP get highlighted instead of HTTP.

The issue is that nothing I do seems to change the output. HTTP continues to get colored, and HTTTP is ignored.

Here is the section of the lexer that contains my change:

```
tokens = {
    'root': [
        (r'(GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)( +)([^ ]+)( +)'
         r'(HTTTPS?)(/)(1\.[013])(\r?\n|$)',
         bygroups(Name.Function, Text, Name.Namespace, Text,
                  Keyword.Reserved, Operator, Number, Text),
         'headers'),
        (r'(HTTTPS?)(/)(1\.[013])( +)(\d{3})( +)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n|$)',
         bygroups(Keyword.Reserved, Operator, Number, Text, Number,
                  Text, Name.Exception, Text),
         'headers'),

         (r'([^\s:]+)( *)(:)( *)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n|$)', header_callback),
         (r'([\t ]+)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n|$)', continuous_header_callback),
         (r'\r?\n', Text, 'content')
    ],
    'headers': [
        (r'([^\s:]+)( *)(:)( *)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n|$)', header_callback),
        (r'([\t ]+)([^\r\n]+)(\r?\n|$)', continuous_header_callback),
        (r'\r?\n', Text, 'content')
    ],
    'content': [
        (r'.+', content_callback)
    ]
}
```

Note that "HTTP" is changed to "HTTTP", so I'd expect entries in the doc containing HTTTP now to be colored, but nothing changed.

I made changes to the doc text and saw they were updated in the page, so no cache issues there.

I also deleted a folder Python created called `__pycache__`, no changes to the result. I also trying commenting out all tokens in the lexer, no changes. If I insert invalid syntax, then it fails. If the syntax is correct, it seems like it uses the original code without my changes.

Is there any other cache I should be clearing up?

I'm totally new to Python so I'm a bit lost here.

PS: this HTTTP thing is just a test. I'll make the real changes once I get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the code changes were being seen, but the lexer was never used because Pygments also registered a lexer called html. So I replaced it with mine: `app.add_lexer('http', HTTPLexer())` and I started seeing my changes affecting the generated docs.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove *.pyc files and restart your extension

Comment: The OP already said he deleted pycache, I think he really meant `__pycache__` which contains all the *.pyc files in python-3.x.